# Updating previous Session Array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have an issue on how can I update my Previous array ?
What currently happening to my code is its just adding new session array instead of updating the declared key here's my code:

```
foreach ($items_updated as $key => $added)
{
    if ($id == $added['item_id'])
    {
        $newquantity = $added['item_quantity'] - 1;
        $update = array(
            'item_id' => $items['item_id'],
            'item_quantity' =>  $newquantity,
        );
    }
}

Session::push('items', $updated);
```

Comment: I'm not sure as what you are trying to do but I can see that when you are looping, you will just be overriding the content of the array `$update`, I would suggest to use array_push; perhaps something like `$update[]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$items = Session::get('items', []);

foreach ($items as &$item) {
    if ($item['item_id'] == $id) {
        $item['item_quantity']--;
    }
}

Session::set('items', $items);
```

Comment: It works Thank you Joseph!!! but what does $items as &$item ?
I want to understand it thank you.

Comment: The ampersand means that it's [a reference](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/php-pass-by-reference/) to the individual item array, not a copy. If you were to do `$items as $item`, the `$item` variable would hold a copy of the item in the `$items` array, and decreasing its `item_quantity` property would have no effect on the item in the `$items` array.

Answer (score 3):

If you have nested arrays inside your session array. You can use the following way to update the session: `$session()->put('user.age',$age);`

**Example**

Supppose you have following array structure inside your session

```
$user = [
     "name" => "Joe",
     "age"  => 23
]

session()->put('user',$user);

//updating the age in session
session()->put('user.age',49);
```

if your session array is n-arrays deep then use the dot (.) followed by key names to reach to the nth value or array, like `session->put('user.comments.likes',$likes)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work for you if you are on laravel 5.0. But also note, that I haven't tested it on laravel 4.x, however, I expect the same result anyway:

```
//get the array of items (you will want to update) from the session variable
$old_items = \Session::get('items');

//create a new array item with the index or key of the item 
//you will want to update, and make the changes you want to  
//make on the old item array index.
//In this case I referred to the index or key as quantity to be
//a bit explicit
$new_item[$quantity] = $old_items[$quantity] - 1;

//merge the new array with the old one to make the necessary update
\Session::put('items',array_merge($old_items,$new_item));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Session::forget('key');` to remove the previous array in session.

And use `Session::push` to add new items to Session.

Comment: What would I need is saving again with its same Item_Id but with new Quantity so I think Session::forget('key') is not the solution.