# Laravel - How to change value of key inside Session array

Tags: php, laravel, session

So I am building a cart and I am using Session to store data for guest users. Here is how I store the items.

```
Session::push('cartItems', [
    'product' = > $product,
    'size' = > $request['size'],
    'quantity' = > $request['quantity']
]);
```

If a guest user adds an item with the same size it should only add the chosen quantity to the `cartItem['quantity']`. Here is how I do that:

```
foreach(Session::get('cartItems') as $cartItem) {
    if ($cartItem['product'] - > id == $product_id) {
        $isNewItem = false;
        if ($cartItem['size'] == $request['size']) {
            $cartItem['quantity'] += (int) $request['quantity'];
        } else {
            Session::push('cartItems', [
                'product' = > $product,
                'size' = > $request['size'],
                'quantity' = > $request['quantity']
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a product when a product with the same size already exists in the cart it goes through that part of the code

```
if ($cartItem['size'] == $request['size']) {
    $cartItem['quantity'] += (int) $request['quantity'];
}
```

But the quantity of the `$cartItem` doesn't change at all. How can I change it?

Comment: $cartItem->save(); check if this works (put it inside the if )

Comment: This won't work because I am using Session arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by doing the following:

```
$cartItems = Session::get('cartItems', []);
foreach ($cartItems as &$cartItem) {
    if ($cartItem['product']->id == $product_id) {
        $isNewItem = false;
        if ($cartItem['size'] == $request['size']) {
             $cartItem['quantity'] += (int)$request['quantity'];
             $cartItem->save();
             Session::set('cartItems', $cartItems);
        } else {
            Session::push('cartItems', [
                'product' => $product,
                'size' => $request['size'],
                'quantity' => $request['quantity']
             ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I found this solution by doing some digging. Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765487/updating-previous-session-array-laravel).

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, $cartItem is a temporary loop variable - changing it doesn't affect the session value. Or in other words, you are not updating your session when the sizes are equal.

Laravel has a convenience method push() for pushing to arrays - which you are using already, but unfortunately there is no array "update" method, so you would need to fetch the whole cart, update it as necessary and then set it again:

```
$cartItems = Session::get('cartItems');
$newItems = [];    

foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        if ($cartItem['product']->id == $product_id && $cartItem['size'] == $request['size']) {
                $cartItem['quantity'] += (int)$request['quantity'];
        } else {
                $newItems[] = [
                        'product' => $product,
                        'size' => $request['size'],
                        'quantity' => $request['quantity']
                ];
        }
}

Session::put('cartItems', $cartItems + $newItems);
```